# The set $\bigcup\limits_{n\in\mathbb{N}}(2n -1/2, 2n + 1/2)$ is open - prove it

Tags: calculus, general-topology

We got the set $\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}(2n -1/2, 2n + 1/2)$. And the sentence set $M$ is open if $\mathbb{R}\setminus M$ is completed quantity. That means a set $A$ is called closed if for every convergent sequence in $A$ also has its limit in $A$.

The complement is $(-\infty, 2n-1/2]\cup [2n+1/2,+\infty]$. Can I now simply form the limits with $n$ towards infinity and then we arrive at $(\infty,\infty)$?

Comment: The union of open sets is open. Also, the complement of the union of infinitely many sets does not equal the limit of the complement of those sets.

Comment: Okay, But how can i prove it, that the set is open

Comment: Do you know whether an open interval is open or do you have to prove everything from scratch from closed intervals? If the latter, the complement is just half integers which are all separated by 1 from each other, so any convergent sequence must be one of them eventually.

Comment: Until now I have that the interval is not closed and therefore not compact, can we conclude that it is open, or do we have to show open separately?

Comment: For example, $[0,1)$ is neither open nor closed. You need to show that a set is open either using facts of open sets or by showing it’s complement is closed either using facts of closed sets or the definition directly.

Comment: Okay, But I don‘t how i should show the closed set in this case due to the   complement: (−∞,2−1/2]∪[2+1/2,+∞]. Because with the closed, all convergent sequences are in this interval, so you have to look at the limit?